# Why Nodemailer is working locally but not in Production?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, nodemailer

When I try to send an email locally it works but in production, in the network tab I get everything right just email doesn't want to send and I don't get any error.

```js
  try {
    const { name, email, message } = req.body;

    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      port: 465,
      host: "smtp.gmail.com",
      auth: {
        user: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GMAIL_EMAIL,
        pass: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GMAIL_PASSWORD,
      },
      secure: true,
    });

    const mailData = {
      from: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GMAIL_EMAIL,
      to: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_EMAIL_WHICH_RECIEVES_CONTACT_INFO,
      subject: `Message From ${email}`,
      text: message,
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailData, function (err, info) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      else console.log(info);
    });

    res.status(200).json({ message: "Email sent" });
  } catch (error: any) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
```

Comment: are you trying to send email from `pages/api` or where exactly?

Comment: yes, I'm trying to send from pages/api/send-email and the request is going successfully but I'm not getting the email on production, but locally I get

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I kind of had a similar issue with nodemailer and Next.js, try to wrap the `transporter` in a Promise, hopefully it works for you too:

```
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    transporter.sendMail(mailData, (err, info) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(info);
      }
    });
  });
```

**explanation**: due to the nature of serveless functions, we have to `await` for the email to be sent before moving on. if we don't the serverless function will end before sending the email(because it's short-lived)

however, you should note that this solution is good for sending a few emails, if you're planning to bulk send emails you better use a dedicated email service like sendgrid

Comment: I changed nodemailer with sendgrid, thank you though

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Thanks man! But do you know why such behaviour?

Comment: This one works for me. But what is the difference?

Comment: added an explanation on why this works

Answer (score 0):

for me, adding tls makes it working

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    tls: {
        ciphers: "SSLv3",
    },
    port: 587,
    secure: false,
    auth: {
        user: process.env.MAIL_SENDER,
        pass: process.env.MAIL_PASS
    }
});
```